# How to pair and create a new DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

I have this df where mmsi of 2 ships and their coordinates along with datetime is present.
[image]

I am trying to create a new df where the first column would be pairs

| pairs | starttime | endtime | own_coord | target_coord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [212979000,219592000] | date - 19:07:20 | date-19:07:20 | olat,olon | tlat,tlon |
| [21297900,245451000] | date - 22:40:00 | date-22:41:00 | olat,olon | tlat,tlon |
|  |  |  |  |  |

I tried group by and even applied many logics but now quite working out. How can I acheive this by pairing and getting the timeframes.

My initial df is [image]

and I changed them to the first df by

```
df2 = result.groupby(['own_mmsi', 'target_mmsi', 'datetime']).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({
        'own_lat': x['own_geometry'].iloc[0].y,   # Extract latitude from own_geometry
        'own_lon': x['own_geometry'].iloc[0].x,   # Extract longitude from own_geometry
        'target_lat': x['target_geometry'].iloc[0].y,  # Extract latitude from target_geometry
        'target_lon': x['target_geometry'].iloc[0].x  # Extract longitude from target_geometry
    })).reset_index()
```

Sample code to recreate the df :

```
data = {
    'own_mmsi': [212979000, 212979000, 212979000, 219592000, 236385000, 236385000, 244013009, 244389000, 244870428],
    'target_mmsi': [219592000, 245451000, 245451000, 212979000, 244013009, 244013009, 236385000, 244870428, 249557000],
    'datetime': [
        '2019-01-01 19:07:00', '2019-01-01 22:40:00', '2019-01-01 22:41:00',
        '2019-01-01 19:07:00', '2019-01-01 08:03:00', '2019-01-01 08:04:00',
        '2019-01-01 08:04:00', '2019-01-01 20:51:00', '2019-01-01 21:17:00',
    ],
    'own_lat': [59.148778, 59.704833, 59.707727, 59.150080, 59.330711, 59.330400, 59.327970, 59.111900, 59.106500],
    'own_lon': [10.665456, 10.595289, 10.593991, 10.645380, 10.515833, 10.514336, 10.515833, 9.606330, 9.623235],
    'target_lat': [59.150080, 59.706086, 59.702300, 59.148778, 59.327478, 59.327970, 59.330400, 59.105400, 59.098800],
    'target_lon': [10.645380, 10.579714, 10.582900, 10.665456, 10.515475, 10.515833, 10.514336, 9.627594, 9.599260],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Please supply your code. Also a sample of the original data.

Comment: It looks like all you will need to do is concatenate the relevant columns. Must pairs be a list? Code and data must be supplied so they can be copied, not images.

Comment: @Cam I have provided the source code where I have manipulated the source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can groupby and use apply function on it

Code

```
data = {
    'own_mmsi': [212979000, 212979000, 212979000, 219592000, 236385000, 236385000, 244013009, 244389000, 244870428],
    'target_mmsi': [219592000, 245451000, 245451000, 212979000, 244013009, 244013009, 236385000, 244870428, 249557000],
    'datetime': [
        '2019-01-01 19:07:00', '2019-01-01 22:40:00', '2019-01-01 22:41:00',
        '2019-01-01 19:07:00', '2019-01-01 08:03:00', '2019-01-01 08:04:00',
        '2019-01-01 08:04:00', '2019-01-01 20:51:00', '2019-01-01 21:17:00',
    ],
    'own_lat': [59.148778, 59.704833, 59.707727, 59.150080, 59.330711, 59.330400, 59.327970, 59.111900, 59.106500],
    'own_lon': [10.665456, 10.595289, 10.593991, 10.645380, 10.515833, 10.514336, 10.515833, 9.606330, 9.623235],
    'target_lat': [59.150080, 59.706086, 59.702300, 59.148778, 59.327478, 59.327970, 59.330400, 59.105400, 59.098800],
    'target_lon': [10.645380, 10.579714, 10.582900, 10.665456, 10.515475, 10.515833, 10.514336, 9.627594, 9.599260],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df= df.sort_values(['own_mmsi', 'datetime']).reset_index(drop=True)
    
# Define columns for the pairs
grp_col=['own_mmsi', 'target_mmsi']
columns1 = ['own_lat', 'own_lon']
columns2 = ['target_lat', 'target_lon']

# Group by 'own_mmsi' and 'target_mmsi'
result_df = (
    df.groupby(grp_col).apply(lambda grp: pd.Series({
        'pairs': grp[grp_col].values.tolist()[0],
        'starttime': grp['datetime'].min(),
        'endtime': grp['datetime'].max(),
        'own_pair': grp[columns1].values.tolist(),
        'target_pair': grp[columns2].values.tolist()
    }))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output

```
pairs   starttime   endtime own_pair    target_pair
0   [212979000, 219592000]  2019-01-01 19:07:00 2019-01-01 19:07:00 [[59.148778, 10.665456]]    [[59.15008, 10.64538]]
1   [212979000, 245451000]  2019-01-01 22:40:00 2019-01-01 22:41:00 [[59.704833, 10.595289], [59.707727, 10.593991]]    [[59.706086, 10.579714], [59.7023, 10.5829]]
2   [219592000, 212979000]  2019-01-01 19:07:00 2019-01-01 19:07:00 [[59.15008, 10.64538]]  [[59.148778, 10.665456]]
3   [236385000, 244013009]  2019-01-01 08:03:00 2019-01-01 08:04:00 [[59.330711, 10.515833], [59.3304, 10.514336]]  [[59.327478, 10.515475], [59.32797, 10.515833]]
4   [244013009, 236385000]  2019-01-01 08:04:00 2019-01-01 08:04:00 [[59.32797, 10.515833]] [[59.3304, 10.514336]]
5   [244389000, 244870428]  2019-01-01 20:51:00 2019-01-01 20:51:00 [[59.1119, 9.60633]]    [[59.1054, 9.627594]]
6   [244870428, 249557000]  2019-01-01 21:17:00 2019-01-01 21:17:00 [[59.1065, 9.623235]]   [[59.0988, 9.59926]]
```

Answer (score 0):

So if your groupby is giving you what you want then and you just then want to concat 'own_mmsi' and 'target_mmsi' try this. So this will get you close you just need to do the same thing with the two target columns.

```
data = {
    'own_mmsi': [212979000, 212979000, 212979000, 219592000, 236385000, 236385000, 244013009, 244389000, 244870428],
    'target_mmsi': [219592000, 245451000, 245451000, 212979000, 244013009, 244013009, 236385000, 244870428, 249557000],
    'datetime': [
        '2019-01-01 19:07:00', '2019-01-01 22:40:00', '2019-01-01 22:41:00',
        '2019-01-01 19:07:00', '2019-01-01 08:03:00', '2019-01-01 08:04:00',
        '2019-01-01 08:04:00', '2019-01-01 20:51:00', '2019-01-01 21:17:00',
    ],
    'own_lat': [59.148778, 59.704833, 59.707727, 59.150080, 59.330711, 59.330400, 59.327970, 59.111900, 59.106500],
    'own_lon': [10.665456, 10.595289, 10.593991, 10.645380, 10.515833, 10.514336, 10.515833, 9.606330, 9.623235],
    'target_lat': [59.150080, 59.706086, 59.702300, 59.148778, 59.327478, 59.327970, 59.330400, 59.105400, 59.098800],
    'target_lon': [10.645380, 10.579714, 10.582900, 10.665456, 10.515475, 10.515833, 10.514336, 9.627594, 9.599260],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.groupby(['own_mmsi','target_mmsi']).agg({'datetime' : ['min', 'max'], 'own_lat': ['min', 'max'], 'own_lon': ['min', 'max']})

# make new column
df['paris'] = ''

# flattern headers
df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]

# reset index
df = df.reset_index()

# makes new cols
df['own_lat'] = list(df[['own_lat min','own_lat max']].values)
df['own_lon'] = list(df[['own_lon min','own_lon max']].values)
# remove cols
df = df.drop(columns=['own_lat min',    'own_lat max',  'own_lon min',  'own_lon max'])
# iterate columns
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'paris'] = [str(row['own_mmsi']) + "," + str(row['target_mmsi'])]
```

output

```
own_mmsi    target_mmsi datetime min    datetime max    paris   own_lat own_lon
0   212979000   219592000   2019-01-01 19:07:00 2019-01-01 19:07:00 [212979000,219592000]   [59.148778, 59.148778]  [10.665456, 10.665456]
1   212979000   245451000   2019-01-01 22:40:00 2019-01-01 22:41:00 [212979000,245451000]   [59.704833, 59.707727]  [10.593991, 10.595289]
2   219592000   212979000   2019-01-01 19:07:00 2019-01-01 19:07:00 [219592000,212979000]   [59.15008, 59.15008]    [10.64538, 10.64538]
3   236385000   244013009   2019-01-01 08:03:00 2019-01-01 08:04:00 [236385000,244013009]   [59.3304, 59.330711]    [10.514336, 10.515833]
4   244013009   236385000   2019-01-01 08:04:00 2019-01-01 08:04:00 [244013009,236385000]   [59.32797, 59.32797]    [10.515833, 10.515833]
5   244389000   244870428   2019-01-01 20:51:00 2019-01-01 20:51:00 [244389000,244870428]   [59.1119, 59.1119]  [9.60633, 9.60633]
6   244870428   249557000   2019-01-01 21:17:00 2019-01-01 21:17:00 [244870428,249557000]   [59.1065, 59.1065]  [9.623235, 9.623235]
```

Comment: The main aim was to find the start and end time based on the data['datetime'] and then make pairs and concatenate the own and target geometry. Kindly refer to the new df posted as the dtypes are different. I have used the `df2.groupby(['own_mmsi','target_mmsi'])['datetime'].agg([min, max])` to get the time of each mmsi group by groupby but I am not able to concatenate the lat, lon of both target and own inbetween these min and max into a column.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet @cam but the lat lon are single number I wanted to concatenate them together inbetween these time frames in a list or something. For eg:  [212979000,245451000] will have own_lat as 59.704833, 59.707727 and own lon as 10.595289, 10.593991.The pairs should have all the lat lons between the timeslices.

Comment: I would be needing the start time end time for the pair **(212979000,212979000)** which is **22:40:00 and 22:41:00** and own lats would have **[59.704833,59.70727]**, own lons would have **[10.595289,10.593991]** and vice versa for tarlats and tarlons.